# Avoid duplicate string in array

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$events = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'event','post_status' => 'publish'));
        if ( $events ) :
        echo '<ul class="event-months">';
            foreach ( $events as $event ) {
                $metabox = get_post_meta( $event->ID, 'event_options', true );
                $month = isset($metabox['start_month']) ? $metabox['start_month'] : '';

                var_dump($month);

                  echo '<li><a href="" title="">' . $month . '</a></li>';
            }
    echo '</ul>';
        endif;
```

It prints this:

```
string 'January' (length=7)
string 'February' (length=8)
string 'January' (length=7)
```

but i want it to print like this:

```
string 'January' (length=7)
string 'February' (length=8)
```

should avoid duplicate string.

Comment: use array_unique to removes duplicate values from an array. for example: `array_unique($month);`

Comment: Yes i already tried this
$month = implode('\n',array_unique(explode('\n', $month))); but it is doing nothing.

Comment: @Ask4Tec store the data in $month[]  , in this case you'll end up with all the values in an array. At the moment $month is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
$events = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'event','post_status' => 'publish'));
    if ( $events ) :
    echo '<ul class="event-months">';
        foreach ( $events as $event ) {
            $metabox = get_post_meta( $event->ID, 'event_options', true );
            $month[] = isset($metabox['start_month']) ? $metabox['start_month'] : '';
        }

        $unique_month = array_unique($month);

        foreach ($unique_month as $month)
        {
            var_dump($month);
            echo '<li><a href="" title="">' . $month . '</a></li>';
        }

    echo '</ul>';
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php, but maybe pseudo code could help:

```
for each event in events
   for each test_event in events
       var cnt = 0
       if event == test_event then cnt++
   next
   if cnt > 1 (you should always match once)
       break/skip
   else
       display
   end if
 next
```

Basically, put a nested loop before you do anything to check events have been duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'event','post_status' => 'publish'));
$events=array_unique($events);
```

Comment: Even though this might do the trick, it would be good practice to explain it a little bit.